# filtered data from vuex not reactive in vue component

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a vuex store with two data points:

eventGroups - holds meta information about all events associated with that group, and is used to render a bunch of `<li>` elements together.

events - holds event data, has an eventGroupId, and has all the data necessary to display the event in an `<li>`

my main app is rendering a bunch of event group elements and may look like: `<event-group :id="event.eventGroupId">`.  As you can see it's passing in the id for that event group.

the eventGroup component has a `computed` property

```
computed: {
  events: function() {
    return this.$store.state.events.filter( event => event.eventGroupId === this.id );
  });
}
```

my problem is that the computed `events` property is actually an array since I'm using `filter`, so it's non-reactive.  When I update event code anywhere in the codebase, it's not registering as a change to the computed `events` property.  I'm stuck in a weird environment where it may not be so easy to `import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';` and make use a getter to find the matching events.  Is there another way I can make this reactive?

Here's the relevant parts of my vuex store:

```
return new Vuex.Store({

  getters: {

    getNextId: function( state ) {
      return function( resource ) {
        return this[ resource ].length > 0
          ? Math.max.apply( Math, Object.keys( this[ resource ] ) ) + 1
          : 0;
      }.bind( state );
    }
  },

  actions: {

    addEvent: function( store, event ) {
      event.startDate = moment( new Date( event.startDate ) );
      event.endDate = moment( new Date( event.endDate ) );
      event.startTime = event.displayDate[ 1 ];

      store.commit( 'setItem', { resource: 'events', id: store.getters.getNextId( 'events' ), item: event } );
    },

    updateEvent: function( store, event ) {
      store.commit( 'updateItem', { resource: 'events', id: event.id, item: event.data } );
    }
  },

  mutations: {

    setItem: function( state, payload ) {
      payload.item[ '.id' ] = payload.id;
      Vue.set( state[ payload.resource ], payload.id, payload.item );
    },

    updateItem: function( state, payload ) {
      Vue.set( state[ payload.resource ], payload.id, Object.assign( {}, state[ payload.resource ][ payload.id ], payload.item ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: for `When I update event code anywhere in the codebase,`, ,can you share the codes how you update the event data (like event id or else)?

Comment: I would do it through a vuex action, but great question, I know Objects and Arrays can become non-reactive if you don't follow the suggestions in the caveats section.  I'll edit the question with more details around that @Sphinx.

Comment: @Sphinx, now that I've edited the question, I might change the events by calling the `updateEvent` action with something like `this.$store.dispatch( 'updateEvent', { id: this.id, data: { showDetails: this.showDetails } } );`

Comment: are you sure your `event.id` is the index of the `events` array?

Comment: yes, I may change that to be handled in a different way in the future, but after the edit I can check the value in the store and updates are being process correctly.

Comment: check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7shq6aok/1/) which simulate your set/update approach.

Comment: @Sphinx, I think you missed the point by a bit.  The issue isn't how I'm saving the data, it updates in the vuex store, and stays reactive.  The issue exists in a child component which is passed an `eventGroupId`, and then uses a computed property to get a list of events in each group using a `.filter()` function.  `.filter()` returns an array, not a reactive array, so even though the event data updates, the list of events in each group derived using the `.filter()` function is static and doesn't respond.